# Exit 0 vs. Return 0 Python Preference

Tags: python

I'm using a Python script to farm out some subprocesses to some other Python scripts. I need to make sure the Python subprocesses run successfully. Is there a convention on whether it is better to `exit(0)` or `return 0` at the end of a successfully run Python script?

I don't think it matters from a functional perspective, but I'm wondering whether one is preferred.

Comment: I think `sys.exit(0)` is more clear, also checkout the [errno](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) module for standard exit codes.

Comment: erm... python does *not* have a `main` function so your choice is to call `sys.exit` or *not* calling it. There's no such a thing as `return 0`, since it would raise a `SyntaxError` when outside a function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shall always use `sys.exit(exit_code)`

`return 0` will not be seen on system level.

Following (**wrong**) code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    return 0
```

is wrong and complains on last line, that there is standalone `return` outside a function

Trying this will not complain, but will not be seen on system level:

```
def main():
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Correct is:

```
import sys

def main():
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does exit(0) vs sys.exit(0) matter?

Comment: @PhilBraun I have always seen only `import sys` followed by `sys.exit(0)`. Other option (which I do not recall to see) is `from sys import exit` followed by `exit(0)`. But your question made me to test, if I can call `exit` without importing from `sys` and it really works (Python 2.7.6). So it works, but I would recommend using the `import sys` followed by `sys.exit(code)` idiom.